# Deadline Monotonic formula with same priority

Tags: process-scheduling, real-time

I have a question related with the response time of Deadline Monotonic scheduling...let's assume that there are 4 tasks, and the processor only allows to have 3 task priorities, thus there will be 2 of 4 tasks that will have same priorities. Tasks with same priorities will be processed in FIFO order. Do you know the formula to calculate the response time for those 4 tasks under that condition?
or do I have to only modify the formula for calculating the response time for Deadline Monotonic scheduling?

Your response is really appreciated for this matter, thx beforehand.